# Can php sessions overlap in codeigniter app?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I am trying to determine if it is possible for php sessions to overlap. I noticed a very odd error that I cannot reproduce and am just trying to see if possible for problems to happen with session overlap. (Just to rule it out)

I have the following in application/config/database.php

```
$client_name = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 0, strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], '.'));

$db['default']['hostname'] = "server";
$db['default']['username'] = "staging";
$db['default']['password'] = "PASSWORD";
$db['default']['database'] = "staging_$client_name";
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = "app_";
$db['default']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = "";
$db['default']['char_set'] = "utf8";
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_unicode_ci";
```

Also I am also using the session library found at (replaces code igniters session library with native sessions:
http://www.philsbury.co.uk/index.php/blog/code-igniter-sessions/

I am using memcached for storing of sessions. The error that is happening is somehow data is ending up in session that I don't think should. Next time it happens I will have more info, but I am just trying to rule out if sessions can overlap in any sort of way.

EDIT: IS there a cleaner way of doing this (Available in php natively)? Is $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] always available and safe to use?

```
    session_start();

      if (!$this->userdata('domain'))
      {
          $this->set_userdata('domain', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
      }

      if ($this->userdata('domain') != $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])
      {
          die(lang('common_session_hijacking_attempt_no_access_allowed'));
      }
```

Comment: Session hijacking maybe? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking

Comment: Is it possible that someone could hijack a session and then use that session on another domain?

Comment: I just tried this and it appears to be possible. How can I prevent this?

Comment: I'm not an expert, so I would suggest to google it (OWASP is always a good start for security related issues https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_hijacking_attack). I always store the user's IP in session and check it on every request. Not foolproof (man in the middle, ...) but an improvement at least and easy to implement

Comment: It is not really session hijacking it is more like session sharing. Example login at sub1.domain.com then grab session id. Go to sub2.domain.com put session id form sub1. Now able to be logged in without logging in.

Comment: should you not work with some sort of acl then? Or store for which sub(s) the user is logged in, and only allow access there?

Comment: If I store the domain in the session I think that will work. I have updated my question with the info. Let me know if you think this makes sense

Answer (score 2):

You just need to set the domain for the cookie the PHP session ID is in.

> bool setcookie ( string $name [, string $value [, int $expire = 0 [, string $path [, **string $domain**[, bool $secure = false [, bool $httponly = false ]]]]]] )
>
> **domain**
>
> The domain that the cookie is available to. Setting the domain to 'www.example.com' will make the cookie available in the www subdomain and higher subdomains. Cookies available to a lower domain, such as 'example.com' will be available to higher subdomains, such as 'www.example.com'. Older browsers still implementing the deprecated » RFC 2109 may require a leading . to match all subdomains.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Basically, any cookie available to `yoursite.com` will be available to ANY subdomain of that, but if you set the domain to `subdomain.yoursite.com` it won't be available to the parent.

EDIT:

I misunderstood what the problem was, I think in the case of people copying the cookie, what you could do is set the `session` save location based off the HTTP HOST:

```
session_save_path("/tmp/" .  $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

And then it theoretically should have the session on a per subdomain basis - even if the SESSION ID matches... it wouldn't find it for that subdomain.  But I could be wrong.

Or, since you are on memcache, you could apply the concept, and modify the library to namespace your sessions:

```
$_SESSION[$key] = $val;
```

becomes:

```
$_SESSION[$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']][$key] = $val;
```

and

```
return ( ! isset($_SESSION[$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']][$item])) ? false : $_SESSION[$item];
```

becomes

```
return ( ! isset($_SESSION[$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']][$item])) ? false : $_SESSION[$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']][$item];
```

etc.

Comment: But the problem is. 1. Log into one subdomain (cookie domain set on sub1.domain.com). Copy PHPSESSID value from cookie. 2. Go to 2nd subdomain. Replace PHPSESSID value from sub1. 3. You are now logged into domain 2

Comment: since we are talking session here, that would need to be done with `session_set_cookie_params`, not `setcookie`. And I think the full host is already used on a default php install. And as @ChrisMuench stated, not really relevant when someone starts tampering with the cookies.

Comment: good edit though, I would do something similar (and I would add an IP check, just to make sure)

Comment: I am using memcache so I don't think that will work. Can HTTP_HOST be forged?

Comment: Dave, do you think my solution above will work correctly. (Shown above).  I think it is along the same line. is $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] safe...could it be forged?

Comment: Anything `$_SERVER` is safe - the entries in the array are created by the web server. There is no "guarantee" that a server will provide it (some $_SERVER variables exist on Apache but not on nginx, for example), but if it does provide it you know it hasn't been forged.